# Coloring ParametricPlot of several complex functions

Tags: plotting, legending, style

I want to PlotLegends -> "Expressions" for G with different colors where

`G = {{Sqrt[1 - x] + I Sqrt[x]}, {Sqrt[1 - x] - I Sqrt[x]}}`

I tried the following

`ParametricPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ G , {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

This gives

[image]

while `G1=Sqrt[1 - x] + I Sqrt[x]`, `G2=Sqrt[1 - x] + I Sqrt[x]` .Thus `G={{G1},{G2}}` and for G1, I got

`ParametricPlot[{Re[G1], Im[G1]} , {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

[image]

and for G2, I got

`ParametricPlot[{Re[G2], Im[G2]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

[image]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of functions should be a simple `List`

```
G = {Sqrt[1 - x] + I Sqrt[x], Sqrt[1 - x] - I Sqrt[x]};
```

Use [`ReIm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) and since [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ReIm /@ G], {x, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im}),
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[G, {0.7, 0.65}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

H.
The problem with coloring is usually solved by evaluating the expression passed as an argument before drawing. In your case however you'll need to also extract or flatten your list of lists.

So either try this:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[First@#], Im[First@#]} & /@ G], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

or this:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Flatten@G], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: I run these and I got the Expressions but with empty curves on complex plane..

Comment: You must have used a different G, with G = {{Sqrt[1 - x] + I Sqrt[x]}, {Sqrt[1 - x] - I Sqrt[x]}} I get exactly the same result as the second answer you've got.